# Python (matplotlib) only show normalized values, how do I get absolute values

Tags: python, matplotlib

> > > Please have a check at this code, input data is much larger than 1, the plotted data has max value of 1, so it has to be normalized. I would like them to be absolute values. How can this be done. Many thanks.

```
import numpy as np
from fipy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import warnings
import time
import pdb
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```

> ## Declare variable values

```
critical_radius = 1e-10             
moments = 4                         


xf = 5e-3                           
yf = 2.95e-4                       

nx = 100                            
ny = 100                            
nelm = nx*ny                       

dx = xf / (nx - 1)                 
dy = yf / (ny - 1)
```

> ## Create a 2D mesh

```
mesh = Grid2D(dx=dx, dy=dy, nx=nx, ny=ny)

phi = CellVariable(name = "moment 0",mesh = mesh, value = 0.)             

phi_ss = phi.copy() 

print(phi_ca)
store_no_180=np.load('store_no_180.npy')
```

> show the values of the data

```
a=store_no_180[99,0,:]  
phi_ss.value=a

viewer= Viewer(vars=phi_ss,title = "moment0")
viewer.plot()
```

[image: the values in the figure are normalized, I would like it to be absolute values]

Comment: It is impossible to tell from this what the problem is without knowing what "Viewer" does.

Comment: This seems to be a question about fipy rather than matplotlib